# Run VBS inside BAT/PY

Tags: python, vbscript

I'm seeking a way to execute a VBS script without saving it to the disk. My primary language is Python, but I'm open to exploring the use of batch files to achieve this goal. Can anyone offer guidance or a solution for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a COM object to run VBScript (or JScript) code embedded directly in your Python script. Here's an example: [(credit)](https://kbarik.wordpress.com/2019/07/21/best-way-to-execute-vbscript-and-return-values-using-python-win32com-module/). Prerequisite: pywin32 (`pip install pywin32`)

```
import win32com.client
vbhost = win32com.client.Dispatch("ScriptControl")
vbhost.language = "vbscript"
script = """
Dim myReturnValue
Function ExampleMethod()
myReturnValue = 9
Msgbox myReturnValue
End Function
"""
vbhost.AddCode(script)
vbhost.Run("ExampleMethod")
output = vbhost.Eval("myReturnValue")
print (output)
```

However, there's a catch. `ScriptControl`, by default, uses `msscript.ocx` which is 32 bit only. Unless you can run your Python script in 32 bit, you'll need an alternative ScriptControl for 64 bit. Fortunately, there's one available for free [here](https://tablacus.github.io/scriptcontrol_en.html). Install that control and the code above will then work in 64 bit.

If you only need to run individual shell commands from Python, you can do it using the `WScript.Shell` object which works fine in 64 bit. Here's an  example: [(credit)](https://python-list.python.narkive.com/VVyaDUZw/python-and-windows-scripting-host).

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
rslt=shell.Popup("Would you like to run Notepad?", 0, "Python WSH Test!",35)
if rslt == 6:
  shell.run("notepad")
else:
  shell.Popup("Maybe next time.", 4, "Bye!")
```

In some cases, it's easier to translate the VBScript code to Python and avoid this complication.

Comment: Please don’t recommend ChatGPT as a source of code generation even if just translating one language to another. It fails a lot more than it works.

Comment: @user692942 I've removed the recommendation, but it does work very well for small chunks of code, and, of course, one must check the results. It just saves a lot of tedious editing. It's a tool that can be used wisely or abused.

Comment: It might work for you and you probably check everything over, but for the average joe, I wouldn't tout it as an approach.

Comment: @user692942 Fair enough. Since this question was closed, will it eventually be deleted? I put considerable effort into researching and posting a solution, so I would prefer it not be lost. Should I write a new, more focused question and post my own answer?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from doing that, it's a good answer and shouldn't be lost. It would be nice to have a canonical for executing VBScript from Python without a file to link to in the future.